# running JSON from python issues

Tags: python, json

Still have an error. Construction like this failed when running json from pyton:

JSON:

$ cat test1.jsonbk
  {"01-create-directories": {"command":"mkdir -p /home/ec2- user/data3/opt/ODS"}}

PYTHON:

cat parse.py

import json
  import sys
  import subprocess
  from pprint import pprint

jdata = open(sys.argv[1])

data = json.load(jdata)

print "start"
  subprocess.call(data['script'], shell=True)
  print "end"
  jdata.close()

OUTPUT:

```
 python parse.py test1.jsonbk
  start
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 11, in <module>
  subprocess.call(data['script'], shell=True)
  KeyError: 'script'
```

TIA

Comment: Please fix the formatting on your question, I'm not sure what code belongs to which part of your question.

Comment: your file isn't valid json. It's mssing a dict curly brace wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not valid JSON.  That data would need to be enclosed in `{}`.

Comment: @daimne: You try to access a key called `'script'` that is not present in your data.

Comment: Thank you. When I changed 'script' in python to 'command' - it gave me error as well.  What do I have to change in a python to make the json code working?

Comment: It worked only if I remove label "01-create-directories".  What do I have to change in python script to make the json code work?

Answer (score -1):

The string you want to load isn't a valid json format. You need to use:

```
'{"01-cd": {"command": "mkdir -p /perm/opt/ODS", "cwd": "/"}}'
```